# check binary data corruption on the file at the disk while trying to read in to memory

Tags: c++, binary

What is the best practice to check that my binary data at the file is not corrupted?

There is some string (lenght + chars) and some MAPs(first size of map, than string).

And when data is corrupted, I get in to an infinite loop, because size of map can be very big value.

Any ideas how to be check and be sure that binary data is not corrupted before/while reading?

Comment: maybe... how to implement it correctly?

Comment: What binary data? Corruption of data, or of media storing the data? Why would you enter an infinite loop? This question is badly in need of details.

Comment: For some/any reason binary file with data can be corrupted on the disk and when program try to read it, it get get an infinite loop, i.e. because at the binary file stored value of std::map size. and correct value is 10. but at the corrupted value it can be any size like 100000000 or -99990900

Comment: The question is too vague. If you're worried that space radiation may corrupt your RAM, then there's probably not a good C++ coding style that can guard you against that. You have to assume that your computer actually *works*. On the other hand, if you're talking about I/O, then you *always* have to check everything anyway, since external data can never be trusted.

Comment: yes, its I/O operation of reading binary data from file to memory.

Comment: Just a quick note on the ranges you gave - why are you using signed integers for a size? You can't have a negatively sized block of memory (at least in any architecture I'm aware of!), so use an unsigned value. Also, set some min/max ranges on those fields. They don't have to be tightly set - just something to stop a hard crash if the value is wrong. For example, if I have a "length of object name" field, I might say it's not going to be more than 512 characters. If the length is greater than 512, something is wrong, so reject the data.

Comment: @polynomial thanks, good idea to implement limits for strings. About signed/unsigned, seems already use unsigned int at every map, but thinking about size_t type and write it to the file (need to clarify this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is some sort of hash/checksum. There are several options:

- One/two's complement addition

  - Pros: Very easy to implement - just add up all the 32-bit DWORDs in your data block.
  - Cons: Not very good at detecting bad data - some common bitskews can break it.
- CRC32

  - Pros: It's fast, relatively easy to implement, has a small hash output size.
  - Cons: Small hash size means there's a small probability of missing bad data.
- MD5

  - Pros: For most intents and purposes (i.e. not crypto) it's collision resistant.
  - Much slower than the previous two, and more complex. There are libs though.
- Parity bits

  - Pros: Can be used to detect *and* correct errors.
  - Cons: Can be difficult to implement properly, increases overall size of data.

Take your pick :)